# What is the equivalent of kinematics for electrics or hydraulics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, electric-circuits

Mechanical-electrical and electrical-hydraulic analogies (system equivalences) are [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical%E2%80%93electrical_analogies).

Kinematics is when you describe the motion of a body without considering forces. Disregarding the dynamics of the platform simplifies analysis substantially. For instance; position, velocity, and attitude of a body can be computed via accelerometer and gyroscope measurements without considering any specific platform dynamics or control inputs.

Since there is the classical equivalence between mechanical&electrical 
and electrical&hydraulics domains, I was wondering whether there is an equivalent approach to kinematics in either electrical or hydraulics domains. If such a kinematical approach is possible, what would be the equivalence?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such analogy for kinematics.

For example, velocity in an electrical circuit is the exact same as velocity in a hydraulic circuit and the exact same as velocity in a mechanical system.   Unlike with dynamic systems, which deal with different physical interactions, kinematics has no concern for what is causing the movements.  It is only looking for a method to describe the movements, which is universal throughout the branches of physics.  There is no analogy, because they all use the exact same variables.

The mechanical-electrical analogies only work when you compare what is being moved and how.  These are specifically things that kinematics doesn't consider.